# How can I use WPF data binding to edit common fields of multiple items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

Similar to the way you can select multiple objects in the Visual Studio designer and change common properties, I would like to do the same in my WPF application.  I am currently binding the selected item of a ListView to a "properties editor" window to edit various properties of the selected object.  My question is what is the best way to exploit data binding, but allow multiple items to be selected and edit all common fields at once?

Edit: Thanks for the answer Freelancer.  To complicate things a little more, whatever is selected on the listview is set as the datacontext of a second listview (the properties editor).  This second listview makes use of ItemTemplateSelector for each property of the selected object.  Any idea how to combine the concept of an ItemTemplateSelector with the concept of a MultiBinding such that I can pass a list of selected objects to the properties editor listview?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `multibindings` for this.

Refer this link for more details about this class>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx

Hope its helpful.